# SoftInputKeyboard sometimes hides field

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm experiencing troubles with a TextInputLayout and the showup of the SoftInputKeyboard.

The softInputKeyboard hides the concerned field only at the second touch.

First touch on email field

[image]

Second touch on email field

[image]
Solutions found on SO I've already tried :

- Use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
- Use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
- Use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
- Wrap layout inside ScrollView

Has anyone a solution for this ? 
Thanks

EDIT :

The problem seems to appear when touching any item that already has a focus on. The keyboard always hides the input.

Comment: can you post your xml layout

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I could edit my original post, but I don't seem to have enough reputation or something. 
Here it is on pastebin : http://pastebin.com/7580tDnn

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you will try to tell but you will try this

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

in your .onCreate() method

Comment: If I do that, how will I allow the user to write his email in the field ? The problem is that the keyboard hides the field the user is writing in, and I would like the screen to scrolldown at this point.

Comment: this Hidden key borad but when user click on your textInputLayout keyboard will appear just try once again and check it. in my case it work properly .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a nestedScroll View as the rootLayout.

so that makes your layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
......
...
your current layout here
...
<...ConstraintLayout...
  android:isScrollContainer="true"
../>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

dont forget `android:isScrollContainer="true"` to the child of the NestedScrollView

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've mentioned, that's part of the solutions I've already tried, and this only wraps up every elements to the top of the screen, and I can't seem to find a way to drag the NestedScrollView to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the problem either :/ I'm starting to think about giving up these type of input